# Can I use a 3-in-1 mix with an overseed machine?

Tags: fertilizer, lawn-repair, overseeding

This [lawncare product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Scotts-Turf-Builder-Thick-R-Lawn-Sun-and-Shade-4-000-sq-ft-40-lbs-30158-1/302684994?) is a 3-in-1 solution containing seed, fertilizer, and soil improver.  Can I use an [overseed machine](https://www.billygoat.com/na/en_us/product-catalog/overseeder/os901-series-hydrostatic-sp-overseeder.html) with the fertilizer and soil improver mixed in or will that harm the machine since those additions are not shaped like a grass seed?

Comment: You need to talk to that machine owner...did you rent this machine?  Another great call for you to make is to a local grass seed spray company.  Far far better than trying to do this yourself...what the heck is 'soil improver' that they've mixed into the mix?  The only ONLY soil improver is decomposed organic matter.  That and an initial fruffing or double digging for the plant bed.  Sounds as if you are considering renting a machine?  Seed spray companies have already invented that wheel and the next best thing to laying sod is a seed spray company!

Comment: I don't have the machine yet but yes, I am renting.  I'm trying to decide between this and a de-thatcher. The overseed machine is less work. Spray like hydroseed? Probably overkill for my budget and the state of my lawn.  I'll confirm with the rental company that this product can be used, thanks.

Comment: Hydroseed is amazing inexpensive.  The cool thing is that they are lawn experts, grass seed growing experts in your area.  Just ask for an estimate  and ask questions with a grass expert walking beside you.  Far as I know that is still free.  It is guaranteed.  They come back just to fill in patches.  Dethatching is something I avoided.  Not healthy for the grass or for your back.  Prevention of thatch by aeration once per year, application of this thatch eating bacteria, bagging clippings...if thatch was bad I'd use a sod cutter and  new sod, start over.

Comment: There are really no patched in my lawn. It's just not thick enough.

Comment: Where is it that you live?  If you are talking about cool season grasses, the problems are; mowing too short, watering too often, too few balanced fertilizer applications...which is the best way to grow a crop of lawn weeds.  Proper installation, proper maintenance and that ensures a gorgeous healthy lawn.  Have you read some of our other questions and answers about lawn installation and care?  You have to send pictures of your lawn, the environment, what zone, what type of soil...your management practices to date.  Thatch usually means cool season grasses.  Grins, we can help more info & pics

Comment: @Merovingian Johnson How large is your lawn? Is there a reason you can't seed and fertilize with a hand spreader?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have cool season lawn grasses.  Thatch is not a problem with 365 days of warmth for decomposition.

Overseeding is not a regular, normal process for lawns...cool season lawns.  Without proper preparation, the correct seed mix, being able to water tiny areas within a huge body of lawn...seed needs a consistently just so moist soil or forget germination.  That means watering when ever that surface soil dries out, sometimes up to 7 times per day in hot weather and bright sun.

This weird specialized watering for your SPOTS lasts until you are able to do the virgin mow.  Then you use that grass, the newbie grass to tell you when to water again until all of that grass is on the same schedule, all with deep roots and NEVER having less than 3 inches of top growth.  Below that length, the grass gets stressed.  Genetically gifted I guess with huge root systems, those root systems need the top growth to FEED those roots or that grass plant is stressed and fragile.  Allows weeds to insert themselves.

I haven't used, probably will never use a 3 in 1 product for overseeding.  Just trying to tell you I've never seen the need for overseeding much less invest in overseeding.

I would most certainly ask for estimates from your local grass companies.  Free.  Might even make sense for your pocket book.  Remember, grass seed or sod companies have to be successful to continue business.  They would be very into teaching you how to grow this monster the lawn so they don't have to do a call back.

So sorry I am not answering your question.  I just am able to know there is more to this story and this problem that I could help fix, help you understand.  I do not think you should mess with this machine. Spraying grass seed, fertilizer, soil improvement stuff from a machine does not ensure a thicker grass.  I've never found overseeding to help at all.  If a lawn isn't thick and lush there is something going on that has to be addressed.  Overseeding is not a regular part of lawn maintenance. A thin lawn needs to be diagnosed first.  Overseeding is rarely a fix.

There is nothing one can spray on soil to improve it.

Adding fertilizer to newly germinating seed is contraindicated.

Comment: Yes, I have cool season grasses.  Unfortunately it's snowing now so I can't get a good picture of my lawn.  I got an evaluation from the a landscaper and a couple fertilization companies prior to deciding to do it myself.  They recommend overseeding.  My lawn is weedy and a bit thin.  They say that the overseeding will help to choke out the weeds, as well as thicken up my lawn.  Many people in my area dethatch or aerate and overseed in the fall.  I'm not concerned about the watering frequently until the new grass is established.

Comment: Mero, I am glad you have cool season grasses.  I am very much an expert with cool season grass crops/lawns.  Landscapers, fertilization companies have little knowledge about lawns.  Overseeding is not the answer.  If your grass crop is unhappy there are reasons why and overseeding will only make more unhappy grasses.  Dethatching is a major bandaid on a problem that should not happen if proper maintenance is in place.  What is the depth of your thatch?  Aeration is done anytime, preferably during warm weather so that the plugs disintegrate better.  Not in the fall.

Comment: If you could send some pictures we could help you to not waste money.  this overseeder might be helpful had you really ripped up your lawn, removed all non decomposed debris, top dressed with 1" of sifted top soil mixed with decomposed organic matter, grade, grade, grade and ROLL with a water filled roller before spraying.  Thatching should not be viewed as a regular practice. Nor should overseeding be considered an annual task. Until problems are corrected and a new seed bed in place, overseeding feeds the birds.  Mowing no less than 3", water deeply and do not water again until footprints.